# How to use Spring Integration 5 with Spring Boot 1.5.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I'm trying to setup a project that uses Spring Boot 1.5.10 and Spring Integration.

It seems that Spring Boot 1.5.x uses the old version of Spring Integration, which is [4.3.14](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/debe15b28422435c4cf5d6fe3ce34c3f316c61ad/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L160).

The project also requires `spring-integration-kafka` which is based on Spring Integration [5.0.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/aebf919f0ee2fe2adb318d153021be8422097816/build.gradle#L64).

So, I'm ending up in a bit of dependencies  hell. Is there a way for Spring Boot 1.5.x to use the latest Spring Integration?

Comment: No there isn't as Spring Integration 5 requires Spring 5 and Spring Boot 1.5 isn't designed, nor tested, nor wil work with spring 5.

Comment: That's not too long to wait for Spring Boot `2.0 GA` though: http://spring-calendar.cfapps.io/ - February 27. Until that you can switch your project to RC1 and develop against latest version. When you come to your GA, Spring Boot 2.0 GA will be there.

Comment: @ArtemBilan yes, that's exactly what I did, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have Spring Boot 1.5.9 and I upgraded to Spring Integration IP 5.0.2. I'm guessing this is why my send/receive messaging is now broken:

```
Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-2" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.toMessage(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/messaging/Message;
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'll just wait until 2.0.0 then...